# SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to debit an account but found no record of a prior credit

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

SOL token has been airdropped successfully on the generated payer address. Still I am getting the above error.

Here's the code:

```
import * as spl from "@solana/spl-token";
import * as web3 from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

const lender = web3.Keypair.generate();
const lenderPk = lender.publicKey;
const payer = web3.Keypair.generate();

async function main() {
    console.log("request airdrop...");
    const tx = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        payer.publicKey,
        web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
    console.log(`Airdrop tx: ${tx}`);

    console.log("creating token mint...");
    const tokenMint = await spl.createMint(
        connection,
        payer,
        lenderPk,
        lenderPk,
        8
    );
    console.log(`Token mint: ${tokenMint}`);

    console.log("creating token address...");
    const lenderTokenAddress = await spl.createAccount(
        connection,
        payer,
        tokenMint,
        lenderPk
    );
    console.log(`Token address: ${tokenMint}`);

    console.log("minting tokens...");
    await spl.mintToChecked(
        connection,
        payer,
        tokenMint,
        lenderTokenAddress,
        lenderPk,
        100e8,
        8
    );

    const lenderTokenAccount = await spl.getAccount(
        connection,
        lenderTokenAddress
    );
    console.log(`Token account account: ${lenderTokenAccount.amount}`);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try waiting until the airdrop is "finalized", you can also try "confirmed"

```
  const tx = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    payer.publicKey,
    web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
  )
  console.log(`Airdrop tx: ${tx}`)
  
  const { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight } =
    await connection.getLatestBlockhash()

  await connection.confirmTransaction(
    {
      blockhash,
      lastValidBlockHeight,
      signature: tx,
    },
    "finalized"
  )
  const newBalance = await connection.getBalance(payer.publicKey)
  console.log("New balance is", newBalance / web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.